# Tamanho de JSON de retorno de AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Estou com dúvidas na utilização do AJAX, estou fazendo uma função para montar uma lista conforme alguns filtros.

Tudo está funcionando perfeitamente, retorno o JSON e monto a tabela. O problema está quando o meu retorno contem muitos dados.

Parece que ainda não recebi todo o pacote de dados e o AJAX já entra no success:

Sendo assim a tabela é montada pela metade.

Já tentei usar callbacks, .done()... Nada resolveu esse meu problema.

Segue o meu código...

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'php/ficha_cadastral_function.php',
        data:{ action: 'pesquisaCliente'
             , cnpj: cnpj
             , razaoSocial: razaoSocial
             , telefone: telefone
             , nomeFantasia: nomeFantasia
             , email: email
             , representante: representante
             , iniScore: iniScore
             , fimScore: fimScore
             , situacao: situacao },
        dataType: 'JSON',
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        success: function(DATA){
            if(DATA.STATUS == 200){
                tabela += ' <form method="post" action="ficha_cliente.php"> ';
                tabela += ' <hr/> ' +
                              ' <div class="col-xs-12" id="lista_cliente"> ' +
                                  ' <table class="table table-bordered small" > ' +
                                      ' <thead> ' +
                                          ' <tr> ' +
                                              ' <th class="text-center">CNPJ</th> ' +
                                              ' <th class="text-center">Razão Social</th> ' +
                                              ' <th class="text-center">Nome Fantasia</th> ' +
                                              ' <th class="text-center">Telefone</th> ' +
                                              ' <th class="text-center">E-mail</th> ' +
                                              ' <th class="text-center">Representante</th> ' +
                                              ' <th class="text-center">Score</th> ' +
                                              ' <th class="text-center">Situação</th> ' +
                                              ' <th class="text-center">Ação</th> ' +
                                          ' </tr> ' +
                                      ' </thead> '  +
                                      ' <tbody id="trListaCliente"> ' ;

                for($i=0; $i < DATA.LINHAS; $i++){
                    tabela  += '<tr>' + 
                                  '<td class="text-center" id="tdCNPJ">' + DATA.DADOS[$i].CNPJ_TITULO + '</td>' + 
                                  '<td class="text-center" id="tdRazaoSocial">' + DATA.DADOS[$i].RAZAO_SOCIAL + '</td>' + 
                                  '<td class="text-center" id="tdNomeFantasia">' + DATA.DADOS[$i].NOME_FANTASIA + '</td>' + 
                                  '<td class="text-center" id="tdTelefone">' + DATA.DADOS[$i].TELEFONE + '</td>' + 
                                  '<td class="text-center" id="tdEmail">' + DATA.DADOS[$i].EMAIL + '</td>' + 
                                  '<td class="text-center" id="tdRepresentante">' + DATA.DADOS[$i].REPRESENTANTE + '</td>' + 
                                  '<td class="text-center" id="tdScore">' + DATA.DADOS[$i].SCORE + '</td>' + 
                                  '<td class="text-center" id="tdSituacao">' + DATA.DADOS[$i].DESC_SITUACAO + '</td>' + 
                                  '<td class="text-center" id="tdAcao">' ;
                                  if(DATA.DADOS[$i].CADASTRADO == false) {
                                      tabela += '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" name="btValor" value="'+DATA.DADOS[$i].CNPJ+'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>';
                                  } else {
                                      tabela += '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" name="btValor" value="'+DATA.DADOS[$i].CNPJ+'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>';
                                  }

                                  '</td>' + 
                               '</tr>';
                }

                tabela +=         ' </tbody> ' +
                              ' </table> ' +
                          ' </div> ';

                tabela += ' </form> ';

                $('#listaCliente').html(tabela);

            } else {

                tabela += ' <hr/> ' + 
                          ' <div class="row"> ' +
                              ' <div class="col-md-12 text-center"> ' +
                                  ' <h3>Sem dados cadastrados!</h3> ' +
                              ' </div> ' +
                          ' </div> ';

                $('#listaCliente').html(tabela);
            }
        },
        error: function(DATA) {
            alerta('Ocorreu um erro ao carregar o cliente! (ERRO - fncPesquisaCliente)', 'danger');
            limpaLista();
        }
    });
```

Alguém teria uma sugestão de como poderia resolver isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

não acredito que não tenha recebido todo o pacote uma vez que uma requisição de resposta sai do servidor backend, o ajax só retorna status 200 quando todo o cabeçalho e conteúdo é devolvido ao navegador. O que acontece com seu código é que alguma das variáveis vindas por json deve conter um valor com aspas ou caracter inválido que está quebrando a concatenação de sua variável table.

Como você pode resolver :

Primeiro tire a prova real! Remova todas as variáveis  DATA.DADOS[$i] do seu html dentro de sua rotina,  rode o código, se funcionar vá inserindo uma a uma. Até descobrir qual delas tem algum carácter inválido, responsável por quebrar a sintaxe do seu javascript. Depois em posse dessa informação basta validar melhor a saída no backend corretamente.

```
<tr>' + 
'<td class="text-center" id="tdCNPJ">'DATA.DADOS[$i].CNPJ_TITULO + '</td>' + 
'<td class="text-center" id="tdRazaoSocial"></td>' + 
'<td class="text-center" id="tdNomeFantasia"></td>' + 
'<td class="text-center" id="tdTelefone">''</td>' + 
'<td class="text-center" id="tdEmail"></td>' + 
'<td class="text-center" id="tdRepresentante"></td>' + 
'<td class="text-center" id="tdScore"></td>' + 
'<td class="text-center" id="tdSituacao"></td>' + 
'<td class="text-center" id="tdAcao">' ;
```

Espero que seja útil essa informação

Comment: Boa ideia Rafael, realmente, removi os campos e vi que o problema é no retorno de um e-mail. Muito obrigado. Aprendi mais uma hoje.

Comment: Disponha meu Rei!!!